# How to reference the Index?

Tags: cross-referencing, koma-script, indexing, labels, imakeidx

How can I reference the index created by the package `makeidx`?

**Minimal working example:**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{hyperref} % creates links on refs
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
    % add something to the index...
    The foobar\index{foobar} is quite impressive!

    % some reference to the index...
    Please follow the \ref{index}.

    % print index...
    \printindex 
\end{document}
```

The obvious `\label{index}` does neither work before nor after `\printindex`.

**Edit** (thanks to daleif): An important fact I forgot to tell: I want the index to be linked at `\ref{index}`. That's why I cannot just say `See index.`

Comment: As long as it is listed in the TOC, I don't think a direct link to it is necessary. *See the index* ought to be reference enough.

Comment: Thanks - good point! I edited my question regarding this...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a hook `\setindexpreamble` in the `scr` classes to add material at the beginning of the index.  You can use this to set your label.  Using just `\ref` will give a blank link, you need either a `\pageref` or a `\nameref`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref} % creates links on refs
\makeindex

\setindexpreamble{\label{index}}

\begin{document}
\label{start}
    % add something to the index...
    The foobar\index{foobar} is quite impressive!

    % some reference to the index...
    Please see the \nameref{index}.

    % print index...
    \printindex 
\end{document}
```

In standard classes such as `article` and `book` you can use the `etoolbox` package to patch `theindex` environment to provide a suitable anchor as follows:

```
\patchcmd{\theindex}{\thispagestyle{plain}}
  {\thispagestyle{plain}\phantomsection\label{index}}{}{}
```

You can usefully refer this either via `\pageref`, or via `\hyperref[index]{text description}` and in particular `\hyperref[index]{\indexname}`

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeindex

\patchcmd{\theindex}{\thispagestyle{plain}}
  {\thispagestyle{plain}\phantomsection\label{index}}{}{}

\begin{document}
\label{start}
    % add something to the index...
    The foobar\index{foobar} is quite impressive!

    % some reference to the index...
    Please see the \hyperref[index]{\indexname}.

    % print index...
    \printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there an equivalent to `\setindexpreamble` for the `book` document class (as opposed to `scrbook`)?

Comment: @JeffIrwin Not by default, but you can patch `theindex`.  I have now extended my answer with such a description.

Answer (score 11):

You can do it with `imakeidx`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref} % creates links on refs

\makeindex[title={Index\label{index}}]

\begin{document}
% add something to the index...
The foobar\index{foobar} is quite impressive!

% some reference to the index...
Please follow the \hyperref[index]{index}.

% print index...
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! it works for me. Started with Latex in 1990 and wrote my thesis in it, hehe

Answer (score 1):

A more 'basic' version, using a `fake` label that is implanted by `\@currentlabel` and `\label`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{makeidx}

\usepackage{hyperref} % creates links on refs

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \newcommand{\@@fakelabelname}{}%
  \newcommand{\definefakelabel}[1]{%
    \gdef\@@fakelabelname{#1}% Make the label name globally available
  }
  \newcommand{\implantfakelabel}{%
    \expandafter\def\csname p@\@@fakelabelname\endcsname{}% Define the dummy 'label' content%
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\csname p@\@@fakelabelname\endcsname\indexname}% Fake `\refstepcounter`
    \phantomsection
    \label{\@@fakelabelname}% 
  }

  \let\latex@@theindex\theindex  % store the original index version
  \let\latex@@theindexend\endtheindex % store the original \endtheindex
  \renewenvironment{theindex}[1][index]{%
    \latex@@theindex% Call the old index start up
    \implantfakelabel% place the fake label here
  }{%
  \latex@@theindexend% End code
}
}
\makeatother

\makeindex



\begin{document}
    % add something to the index...

\chapter{Foo}
    The foobar\index{foobar} is quite impressive!

    % some reference to the index...
    Please follow the \ref{indexfoo}. % Refer to the label

\chapter{Foobar}

    % print index...
\definefakelabel{indexfoo}% how is the label named?
\printindex 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user31729 **1.** I am using the book class and over the years my preamble has become rather ... complicated. **2.** Still, your answer seems to be the only one  not to break anything. **3.** But I don't understand your `how is the label named?` I thought it was `\indexfoo` and, indeed, the console says `./Text-contents/0.tex:470: Undefined control sequence.
l.470 See \indexfoo`
` Not very important but I would like it to work